# runkit compile error against php 5.3.8?

Tags: php, pecl, runkit

It gives me a compile error against 5.3.8. I run phpize, then configure and then make:

```
/bin/sh /root/runkit/runkit-0.9/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/root/runkit/runkit-0.9 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/runkit/runkit-0.9/include -I/root/runkit/runkit-0.9/main -I/root/runkit/runkit-0.9 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/runkit/runkit-0.9/runkit.c -o runkit.lo 
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/root/runkit/runkit-0.9 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/runkit/runkit-0.9/include -I/root/runkit/runkit-0.9/main -I/root/runkit/runkit-0.9 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/runkit/runkit-0.9/runkit.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/runkit.o
/root/runkit/runkit-0.9/runkit.c: In function ‘zif_runkit_zval_inspect’:
/root/runkit/runkit-0.9/runkit.c:61: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘refcount’
/root/runkit/runkit-0.9/runkit.c:62: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘is_ref’
/root/runkit/runkit-0.9/runkit.c: In function ‘zm_deactivate_runkit’:
/root/runkit/runkit-0.9/runkit.c:360: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘zend_hash_apply’ from incompatible pointer type
/root/runkit/runkit-0.9/runkit.c:370: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘zend_hash_apply’ from incompatible pointer type
/root/runkit/runkit-0.9/runkit.c:378: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘zend_hash_apply_with_arguments’ from incompatible pointer type
make: *** [runkit.lo] Fehler 1
```

Comment: do you need the Runkit extension? If not, remove it from your build. It is known to have conflicts with other extensions.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I will need it. It's very old, too?!

Comment: There's not really any good reason to be using Runkit, so yes, I'd drop it.

Comment: Also, why php 5.3.8? That's quite out of date -- The latest version of 5.3 is 5.3.17. (and you might want to try 5.4 too)

Comment: I want to test runkit but I don't have time and I also I don't have time to update php. There are people wanting me to help them but for free?! How old is 5.3.8?

Comment: Answer is here: http://php.net/releases/index.php -- PHP 5.3.8 released on 23-Aug-2011.

Comment: Re Runkit. If you need Runkit-like functionality without the extension, there is a library called [Patchwork](https://github.com/antecedent/patchwork) which does a similar job in pure PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official runkit extension is now hosted on http://github.com/zenovich/runkit
The current master branch fully supports all contemporary PHP versions from 4.4 to 5.3 & 5.4 inclusively.